# What Was the Actual Prophecy About Bringing Balance to the Force?

Tags: star-wars

The prophecy about "the one who will bring balance to the force" is mentioned several times.  From the discussion, the implication is that virgin birth is part of it, along with a few other factors that would make Anakin seem like the person it described.

But is the actual prophecy ever stated anywhere?  Just how much do we know about what it said?  Having just re-watched *The Phantom Menace*, the only clues we get are that it seems to include virgin birth and the high midichlorian count.

It's also interesting that this is the *only* prophecy, at least in the movies and TV show, that is ever mentioned.

Comment: The footnotes to the prophecy are generally omitted regarding its further clauses describing how a Sith Lord clones himself, living on after he explodes and presiding over an arena full of cultists, while having one of his test subjects grow powerful in the Force and lead remnants of the original’s Empire while mentoring a nebulously-associated dark side practitioner related to the prophesied being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the prophecy in Canon is given in *Skywalker: A Family at War* (2021):

> Around this time, Qui-Gon received a coveted offer to join the Jedi Council and thus become one of the 12 Jedi steering the Order and offering guidance to Jedi Masters in the field. To the other members' astonishment, Qui-Gon rejected their proposal, certain that his true path was still unspooling before him. And so it was that, just a few years later, Jedi Master Qui-Gon came to be traveling the galaxy with his Padawan Obi-Wan Kenobi when he happened upon young Anakin, the child whom Qui-Gon came to believe was the individual mentioned in an ancient Jedi prophecy: *"A Chosen One shall come, born of no father, and through him will ultimate balance in the Force be restored."*
>
> (page 15, emphasis in original)

The book is an in-universe biography of the Skywalker family, but doesn't elaborate on the prophecy's source beyond it being an "ancient Jedi prophecy". According to [another Stack Exchange question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/225684/21154), this is also the prophecy text given in *Master and Apprentice*, although I don't have it and can't confirm.

Comment: Can you provide more context to this? Where does it come from, for example?

Comment: @Tango There's unfortunately very little other context given—it's in the section about Anakin's early life, and discusses Qui-Gon's belief in prophecy without elaborating on the history of that particular prophecy. I added the full paragraph to my answer for the context that's there.

Comment: In the first version I read your answer and thought, "Hmmm...Now I want to know more," so adding the context is a big help! May I suggest also adding a line, similar to your comment content, that this is all they say about it - just an offhanded reference? My thought is that would make it complete and not lead people to think, "Is that it? Maybe there's more and I need to look for it."

Comment: @Tango Will do—I'm still reading the book, so it's possible there's more given later. I'll update my answer here once finished in case it sheds more light on the prophecy outside of what we know from the films.

Comment: If you find more, feel free to add it later!

Answer (score 15):

This is from the novelization. It expands a little bit on it but doesn't fully answer your question. This is the only time prophecy is mentioned in the book.

> There  was  a prophecy, so old its origins had long since been lost,  that  a  chosen  one would appear, imbued with an abundance of midichlorians, a being strong with the Force and destined to alter it forever.
>        It was Mace Windu who gave voice to the Council's thoughts. "You  refer to the prophecy," he said quietly. "Of the one who will bring balance to the Force. You believe it is this boy."

Comment: I always felt that Vader did bring balance, at the end of the third film they had two Jedi and two Sith.

Comment: @raybritton Canonically speaking, [what the Jedi Order call "balance" is not the middle point between dark and light side, its the absence of Dark Side use](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force/4297#4297)

Comment: @DavRob60: With a prophesy that old, who is to say what the right meaning of "balance" is?

Comment: @DampeS8N Because George Lucas explicitly said what is the meaning of "balance". And when we speak of Star Wars Canon, George's statement is absolute canon.

Comment: The Wookieepedia has an article on the [Chosen One](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One) which provides all the in-universe background to the prophecy and how Anakin fulfils it.

Comment: @raybritton: Bravo ! The Jedi Force is the same Force of the Sith. The Force is always balanced because there is no difference. Jedis wants to be absolute in universe. `Religion`... Ptff.