# How can the prophecy of the Chosen One be re-interpreted in light of Palpatine's return in the Disney canon?

Tags: the-rise-of-skywalker, anakin-skywalker, star-wars

The explanation I usually hear for Rey playing an equally, if not more, dramatic role in defeating Palpatine compared to Anakin's (while still not formally replacing him as the Chosen One) is that the prophecy referred only to a single, temporary event, one that could be repeated any number of times. I can't help but raise two objections; why is the prophecy centuries old if its events will be overshadowed in a few decades, and why is Anakin alone the chosen one when it seems a new drama will open with every generation?

My question is whether we (fans, theorists) can ever get this to make sense, or whether we have to accept that this is just an incredibly poor improvisation that Disney has had to make due to an acute paucity of creative inputs.

I'm not the most knowledgeable when it comes to Disney lore, so I'd be really glad if this question was discovered by someone with background knowledge about 1) the prophecy and 2) the post-IX future, if any.

To any layman, it would seem as if the Chosen One should provide the foundations for a new Jedi Order and a long-lasting, peaceful Republic. Anakin's legacy here seems to be hesitantly and underwhelmingly portrayed. This may sound like a personal opinion, but I'm genuinely curious why things ended up this way, and what they plan to make out of it.

Comment: [Very related, maybe a dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/225684/58193)

Comment: Thank you, but I couldn't walk off really satisfied without my objections being answered.

Comment: "My question is whether we (fans, theorists) can ever get this to make sense". No. There is no point in trying to get it to make sense.

Comment: RL answer, bad writing...in lore answer it is all a bad dream Luke is having?

Comment: The Sequel Trilogy kinda invalidates Anakin's sacrifice and the prophecy. And Luke is degraded to some incompetent old grumpy man. Only Rey is cool, because she is cool.

Comment: The EU did the same thing, of course. Palpatine returned repeatedly until Luke pushed his spirit into a Force Storm where the spirits of all the dead Jedi ate it. And then more Sith showed up, anyway. The Prophecy only makes sense if you're a PT/OT-only movies-only purist.

Comment: It's a prophecy. Almost by definition they tend to not make much sense or be so vague as to leave plenty of narrative wriggle room!

Comment: I still prefer the EU to Disney because it's better that fanfiction remains in comics rather than being made into grand blockbusters (ruining the franchise while ironically becoming a major hit with newbies). At least the EU didn't recycle the plot of an actual emperor wreaking havoc on the galaxy with an actual empire. That is due solely to Disney's shocking lack of originality.

It really is sad how no one has answered this yet, cause it shows Disney not only did a senseless and dishonorable thing but also covered its tracks so poorly that we're all at a loss.

Comment: "Always in motion is the future."

Answer (score 1):

Anakin fulfilled the prophecy. Rey was not included in the prophecy, though she did rebalance the Force, according to Anakin in *The Rise of Skywalker*. It is possible that this is either a recurring prophecy, that every few generations you need to bring balance to the Force again, or it could be that Rey's time was unprophecied. Then again, it is also completely possible that Disney just remade the OT but slightly different as some strange reboot.