# What's the meaning of "Bring Balance to the Force"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did the Jedi want to bring balance to the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force)

As common sense says, Force will be in balance if there exists both sides of force (including dark side of force). [Jedi always wanted to bring balance to the force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force). But, they didn't want to drop chance of killing a Sith. Isn't killing a Sith a way to imbalance force?
What does exactly "Bring Balance to the Force" mean?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What precisely did you find unsatisfying in the answers to the question you link to?

Comment: I read only accepted answer of linked question before asking..

Comment: This question is different..

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from the previous one, so I'm closing it as a duplicate. If you want it reopened, point out the differences.

Comment: I can drag it to Meta as you're unable to understand the difference between "Why" & "What" (Plus, 'what' is applied to meaning of target). But, why should I bother as I've got the answer... Thanks for the delay before closing!

Comment: I like to think that the prophecy was true: two Jedi (Kenobi/Yoda), two Sith (Vader/Palpatine).  It may not be what the Jedi *wanted*...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(This is a basically a copy-paste of [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4297/45) I already provided to the linked question, the question itself may not be an exact duplicate, but I feel this answer completely answer this question)*

---

What the Jedi Order call "*balance*" is not the middle point between dark and light side, its the absence of Dark Side use:

> Traditional Jedi were keen to keep the Force "in balance". They attempted to achieve this by destroying the Sith and denying the dark side—essentially **"keeping balance" by restoring the Force to its natural state, as they viewed the dark side as "corruption"**.
>   - [Wookieepedia article about "The Force" section "The Jedi Order" paragraph 2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Force#The_Jedi_Order)

Also, about the Chosen One prophecy:

> The idea of balance of the Force, a
>   central tenet of the Jedi Order,
>   refers to the ideal state in which the
>   Force exists in nature, i.e. as the
>   light side. The presence of **the dark
>   side corrupts and destroys this
>   natural balance**, and the Jedi viewed
>   it as their duty to restore it.
>    - [Wookieepedia article about the "Chosen One"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chosen_One)

Finally as for George Lucas' intention:

> **Many fans incorrectly assume that balance refers to an equal mix of both light and dark side users**. However, as George Lucas explains in the introductory documentary for the VHS version *A New Hope, Special Edition*, **this is not the case**:
>
> "[...] Which brings us up to the films 4, 5, and 6, in which Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to **fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe...**"
>
> In an interview, **Lucas compared the difference between the light and dark sides as being like the difference between a symbiotic relationship and a cancer.** A symbiotic relationship is one which benefits both parties and in which neither is harmed, whereas a cancer takes without giving back, eventually causing the death of both parties
>   - [Wookieepedia article about the "Chosen One", Section "Behind the scenes"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chosen_One#Behind_the_scenes)

**Update :** On a side note, I just watch the French translation of *The Phantom Menace* with my son and the "*bring balance to the Force*" concept was translated to "*restaurer l'harmonie dans la Force*" (to restore the harmony to the Force). This is one of the unusual case where the intended concept had a better translation than the original.

Comment: Thanks.. Your answer may not good for that question, but perfect for this one.. :)

Comment: The above Wookieepedia citations contain false information. The balance of the Force does *not* refer to the light side alone. It is a balance between the light and dark sides. The mere presence of the dark side does not disrupt the balance; in fact, it is necessary for balance. Both sides are part of the natural state of the Force. On a related note, Lucas never referred to the dark side as a cancer. He only used a cancer analogy to characterize the unhealthy interpersonal dynamic between the Sith.