# Can you achieve Oneness with the dark side of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I was just wondering if you can achieve oneness with the dark side. Darth Malgus was said to have merged with the Force after he killed his lover and it linked the act to Oneness. So is it possible?

Comment: You will have to define what it means to achieve "oneness". So far, your question seems to answer itself.

Comment: If you're talking the ability to Force Ghost, there were several Sith Lords who came back that way. Exar Kun even found a way to come back physically.

Answer (score 16):

I severely doubt it. Let me explain.

There are (generally) two "sides" to the Force, of course: the "dark" and "light."  But in general, most people misunderstand how there *are* two sides, i.e., is there some greater entity called "the Force" which encompasses the two camps?

The answer to that question is no. "The Force" refers to "the light." In other words, the light side *is* the Force in its natural state. The dark side is simply a perversion of that natural state. See [this answer to "Why did the Jedi want to bring balance to the Force?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4297/2286).

As such, the answer to your question is no. A dark-sided being cannot become one with the Force, or else he would be embracing the light. This is corroborated by the fact that in all canonical sources of oneness to date, it has only been achieved by light-sided Force users.

Here's a quote from *Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith* by Stover (p. 409, hardback, first edition):

> Yoda did not move. "Eternal life. . ."
>
> *The ultimate goal of the Sith, yet they can never achieve it; it comes only by the release of self, not the exaltation of self. It
>   comes through compassion, not greed. Love is the answer to the
>   darkness.*

The italicized text is that of Qui-Gon, who was canonically one with the Force at this point. And given that oneness is essentially becoming one with the Force without dying, it would seem that Qui-Gon is essentially saying that no Sith can ever achieve oneness.

---

Addressing your concern about Malgus: Here is the relevant passage from *Deceived*, the novel in which Malgus feels like he has achieved oneness:

> Thinking of Eleena blew oxygen on the embers of his anger. In life,
>   Eleena had been his weakness, a tool to be exploited by rivals. In
>   death, she had become his strength, her memory the lens of his rage.
>
> He resided in the calm eye of a storm of hate. Power churned around
>   him, within him. He did not feel as if he were drawing on the Force,
>   using it. **He felt as if he were the Force, as if he had merged with
>   it.**

Malgus's feelings and reality are two separate matters.

Comment: Good anwer, but not sure I totally agree. The Siths wanted to bring the Force into complete submission, and Sidious and Plagueis went very far in that diection. I would not be surprised that Darth Vader at its full power could have corrupted the Force completely, and so

Comment: become One with the Dark Side. However such a feat would probably lead to the extinction of life in the galaxy in the long run, as happened on Korriban.

Comment: @ALS: I would find such a scenario unlikely. The Force is infinite, while they are only one person. They could probably become "one" in a local sense, but I don't think any darksider could achieve true oneness with the whole of the Force, and I don't think a finite being (e.g. Anakin) could subjugate an infinite field (e.g. the Force). Of course, what qualifies as true "oneness" is up to debate, but I typically take the definition of "one with the Force" and not just "has corrupted a vast swath around them."

Comment: It is apparent that the Sith equivalent is reincarnation. In looking at the Extended Universe, one finds that Darth Sidious reincarnates into a young clone of himself, prepared prior to his death. This is the preciptating event of the Dark Empire comics.

Comment: Darth Nihilus was eroded by the force he controlled and in turn he became nothing but an empty shell behind his mask that the force welled inside, this is categorized as a wound in the force but it may be the closest the sith have achieved to oneness if Nihilus was nothing but force power behind his mask with what was left of his soul.

Comment: The light side alone is *not* the Force in its natural state. The Force in its natural state includes both the light and dark sides, as Lucas has made clear on various occasions. ( This was also expressed in various Legends EU sources such as *Edge of Victory: Conquest*, *Crucible*, *Tales of the Jedi*, etc. )

Answer (score -3):

The Force itself is just that "The Force" there is no true dark side or light side it all depends on how you manifest the force within yourself

Comment: Welcome to the SFF.se site! On this site we're looking for answers that use sources and/or deductive reasoning/logic to answer the question being asked. You answer seems opinion-based and has no sources, consider editing to make it a better answer. All evidence points to the actual existence of the Dark Side of the Force.