# What happens to the universe if the Force gets too out-of-balance?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

What exactly happens if the Jedi just leave the Force to the Sith?

I can think of plenty of political consequences - the Sith take political control of the galaxy, build an army, and have an empire of their own.  In other words, the consequences have very little to do with Light/Dark balance of the force.

However, while that's happening, the Force is probably going to tilt more and more towards the dark.  What I'm curious about is - what are the consequences of *that*?

Now, I am certainly imaginative enough to think of answers like "things start dying everywhere."  But are there any canon examples/descriptions of Force imbalance consequences for which we can't directly blame some Sith and his/her hunger for power?  Or is there at least any indication that the Jedi's obsession with balance is something more than dogma?

Comment: It explodes. Kaboom!

Comment: @Richard If a universe explodes in a non-universe environment, and there is no external space within which to contain life forms that may register the detonation, does it make a sound?

Comment: Yes, it makes [this sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erFcYsC6JaY&feature=youtu.be&t=8s).

Comment: @Richard Holy crap!  You directed me to a specific time in a Youtube video!  How might I too weave such witchcraft?

Comment: [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff2B8.gif)

Comment: @Richard @#$%@#$!!!!  Much obliged, kind sir!  May you live long and prosper!

Comment: Forty years of darkness! Earthquakes, volcanoes... The dead rising from the grave! Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together... mass hysteria!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**War would intensify and the Sith (and likely other dark-siders as well) would gain strength.**

We know this from to the *Star Wars: The Clones Wars* episode *[Alter of Mortis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Altar_of_Mortis_(episode))*.

> On Mortis, there were three beings, The Son, who embodied the Dark Side, The Daughter, who embodied the Light Side and The Father, who  embodied balance. Eventually, the Daughter died, and the Force became unbalanced. All of Mortis immediately became dark,

and The Father says [this](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s03e16):

> The balance has been broken... As the balance in this world crumbles, so shall war escalate in your galaxy. As my son has descended into the dark side, so have the Sith gained strength.

Eventually,

> The Son is killed, and balance returns.

Comment: Oof..  I asked two questions about the Jedi mythos in the last two days, and both so far only have answers that come from this weird cringe-worthy Garden of Eden parable in the cartoon series.  Has the Star Wars canon really not touched on this outside of it?  Plus, according to an answer to a related question on here -  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4292/31275 - George Lucas seemed to think that the Dark Side is just plain ol' bad, rather than part of the balance.  Is there a disagreement between him and the cartoon?

Comment: ...Also, war seems to be a direct consequence of the Sith doing bad stuff.  Will war escalate because the Sith will have more power (something that has more to do with them, rather than with the Force), or it is that the increase in the Dark Side just makes everyone a jerk?

Comment: @MishaRosnach It's purposely ambiguous, so I can't really answer that question.

Comment: Btw, you mention that at the end "balance returns."  The Internet tells me that the events in the series take place between episodes II and III - Clone Wars and Revenge of the Sith.  It seems, then, that "balance" as described by The Father doesn't really return.  I mean there is still war, isn't there?  A big bad political power ruled by the Sith, with rebels trying to fight against it.  And the whole premise of the original trilogy.  The line of the Sith seems to remain well in place even with the Son gone.

Comment: @MishaRosnach The total imbalance of having a dark side embodiment without a light side embodiment ends, however, the overall imbalance remains. There also seem to be two types of imbalance, Dark side but no light side (or vice-versa), and the imbalance of the dark side existing in the first place. It's all pretty confusing.

Comment: RogueJedi - You know, I'm beginning to side with the Sith here. I mean the Jedi seem to have this weird dogma that's based on some pretty vague stuff at best. The Sith, on the other hand, are like "Screw this. We're gonna go ahead and figure out how to use this thing until further notice." They might be power-hungry maniacs, but at least their grasp on reality seems solid.  And their philosophy doesn't come from a cartoon.

Comment: @MishaRosnach George Lucas' idea of balance at the end of RotJ is the defeat of the Sith. This is because he conceptualised and defined the Force not as divided between light and darkness (in which case balance would require both being equal in power), but as merely natural. The Jedi are simply practitioners of the Force in its natural state. The Sith practices the dark side, however, which is defined as an unnatural perversion and corruption of the natural Force. As such, eliminating the unnatural is the right way to restoring balance.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Personally, "curing" or "purifying" would be more accurate words to what Lucas had in mind, but I guess you won't phrase things that way 30 years after the Holocaust. You should also know you're comparing the Jedi at their worst - when they've already grown arrogant, dogmatic and unconsciously departed from the true way of the Jedi - with the Sith who've always been bad. They are not the Jedi as they used to be, as they should be.

Comment: So... to bring balance to the humanity we must kill all non-good people? `I'm not thinking like this. Just to compare`. Balance is always different things in equal parts. The Force have two sides, but still the same Force.

Comment: @MagnoC No. The Son had to be killed because he had killed the Daughter. While both were alive, there was balance.