# Is the Force sentient?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, sentience

In thinking about this excellent [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112717/what-happens-to-the-universe-if-the-force-gets-too-out-of-balance) it occurred to me that what's probably first needed is an answer to whether **the Force has an awareness of itself?**

Equivalently, we know that living organisms generate the Force, and that there are two sides if we can say that it favors one over the other then the answer must be yes (Presumably the Light Side, if we can show that).

Note that this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force) implies that the Jedi have an agenda to eliminate the Dark Side if at any point we can say the Force always keeps at least a remnant of The Dark Side alive then again the answer must be yes.

Comment: Related (dupe?): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23616/does-the-force-act-like-god-in-star-wars-canon/

Comment: Related, yes. Not sure about the duplicate, note that Obi-Wan described `a disturbance in the Force`. Why would it be disturbed by actions of the Dark Side? Not acting as a traditional God, but say like an ocean that will fill any space, 'good/light' or 'bad/dark'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Darth Sidious and Darth Plagueis seem to think so (and no Midichlorians are involved! Three cheers for Disney!)

According to New Disney Canon novel "Tarkin" by James Luceno,

> Darth Plagueis had once remarked that “**the Force can strike back**.” The death of a star didn’t necessarily curtail its light, and indeed Sidious could see evidence of that sometimes even in Vader—the barest flicker of persistent light. Attacks like the one directed against Tarkin’s moon base and discoveries like the one on Murkhana were distractions to his ultimate goal of making certain that **the Force could not strike back**, and that whatever faint light of hope remained could be snuffed out for good.

Now, that doesn't prove it 100% (they could both be wrong), but you don't "strike **back**" unless you're aware of yourself, since you need to be aware that **you youself have been struck** first to strike **back**.

Additional weak evidence is that in the much-discussed-recently episode of *The Clones Wars* "Altar of Mortis", we had Celestial-descended "The Ones", who were meant to "represent" the Force and its light and dark side... You generally can infer that if a sentient being represents something, that something might be sentient as well.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the type of evidence I was hoping for. Thx.

Comment: DVK - But wouldn't the force being conscious potentially resolve a bunch of balance issues?  I mean if the Force is rooting for the good guys - and is willing to intercede on their behalf - why are the bad guys such a problem?  Does the Force have the ability to strike back, but has no say over who uses it and to what extent?  Now, yes, you do say it doesn't prove stuff 100%.  Perhaps the question is, *How much* sentience does the Force have?  And how much self-control?  And if it can be subjugated in spite of its sentience, can we *really* trust it to keep the universe in working order?

Comment: I wasn't implying a traditional consciousness, but this: `They use the darkness that is always there. That has always been there. Greed and jealousy, aggression and lust and fear -- these are all natural to sentient beings. The legacy of the jungle. Our inheritance from the dark.` - [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force), may shed some light. I'm thinking the darkness of say _space_ is always there, it's only the stars that allow us to see.

Comment: @MishaRosnach - welcome to human theology for the last 3000 years. You just stumbled onto one of the big problems with the concept of a "good" deity :)

Comment: @DVK Ha.  The thought occurred to me as well.  But can you blame me for assuming the authors of the Star Wars universe knew enough to improve on that mess?

Comment: @MishaRosnach - Because the Force has a dark side. ;)  The Jedi believe that the Force is guiding them. The Sith believe that the Dark Side is guiding them. They’re both probably right. They’ve both won some rather major victories (two decades of Galactic Empire, anyone?), so it’s not as if one side or the other always wins. “The Force” appears to be an entity beyond human morality, perhaps without what we would recognize as consciousness. The dark side and the light have agendas, but they are both part of the Force. That’s what Bendu tells me, anyway.