# Did Rey become a Jedi at the end?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

We know for sure that Rey wanted to be a Jedi during *The Last Jedi* (it was Luke that didn't want to be one). Rey even takes the Jedi temple books.

But a funny thing happened on the way to being a Jedi. It turns out

> Rey is the grand-daughter of the one and only Emperor Palpatine, aka Darth Sidious, the last Sith lord

As if that weren't bad enough, we have the re-emergence of the "balance the Force" trope, which [does not mean what you think it means](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force). At the end we have Rey

> bury Luke and Leia's lighsabers and light her own shiny new yellow one) and take the name Skywalker.

It kinda leaves things vague at the end of the movie, however.

> All of the known Jedi are now dead/ghosts, and there are no more Skywalkers. We don't know how much Leia trained Rey either.

So did Rey make it? Is she a Jedi now? Or is she simply some really adept Force user who eschews titles and orders, similar to [Ashoka Tano](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano) or the [Gray Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gray_Jedi)? Looking for some indication of how Rey saw herself.

Comment: Define Jedi. Technically there was no Jedi Order left unless if she decided to create her own organization called the Jedi Order that picks up where the last one left, and then she could declare herself a Jedi.

Comment: After TLJ I was all set for the passing on of the Jedi and Sith orders, and the chance for something *new* to arise.  <sigh/>  As things stand now, I bet Disney can dig up some more Palpatine clones if they ever need to go back to the well...

Comment: I think the implication at the end of the film is that she’s neither Jedi nor Sith but somewhere in between.

Comment: #joke - she's gone beyond. Rey is now setting up a United Church of Force-Users which is affirming of all shades of force use

Comment: she did seemingly receive more training than luke did....AND did have the jedi books

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe It wouldn't be the first time this happens. Wasn't this also the case in the Expanded Universe -- now demoted to "Legends" non-canon -- when Luke founded the "New Jedi Order"? Or am I misremembering? (never liked the EU anyway). Rey could be founding the Really New Jedi Order :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of *The Last Jedi* Rey is a fully paid up member of the Jedi order, trained by a master, having completed her own lightsaber and given a trial to complete. If she was in the old (pre-Empire) order, her rank would be 'Jedi Knight'.

> Palpatine had wanted Rey for himself. But she chose to be their conduit. Their vessel. ***She was a Jedi***.
>
> Rey moved an arm. Then a shoulder. She let the voices surround her, fill her, strengthen her. She turned over, placed a palm to the ground, pushed up.
>
> We stand behind you.
>
> Rise in the Force.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

There's every indication that she'll attempt to found a new Jedi order, using her training from Luke and Leia and her knowledge of the sacred texts as a jumping-off-point toward the rank of 'Jedi Master'.

Comment: Also, she built her own lightsaber, in canon (G or C?) that was considered part of getting to be a Jedi

Comment: She'll go off to start her own Jedi Order... then decide years later that the Jedi must die.

Comment: @Omegacron - With the Sith dead, balance is finally returned to the Force so there's more likely to be a thousand years/generations of peace

Comment: Technically, one Grey Jedi in the galaxy represents complete balance. After all, many of the truths we cling to depend greatly on our own point of view ;-P

Comment: @Omegacron - Using the dark side of the Force (at all) represents an imbalance.