# Is the Force balanced after the events of Episode IX?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

*Star Wars* is mostly about the Skywalkers bringing balance to the Force and destroying the Sith. Is the Force balanced after the events of Episode IX?

This question arises considering the fact that there are essentially no known Sith at this point of time, so how could it be balanced?

Comment: Basically a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force

Comment: *"Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe"* ~ George Lucas

Comment: I've always thought that at the time Anakin was a child that the force leaned too much to the light (there seemed to be many more Jedi than Sith. So Anakin balanced the force by adding to the dark side while he was alive.

Comment: @Valorum  I don't think that George Lucas quote answers the question,  because Disney. _"Perhaps Lucas skipped the premiere of The Rise of Skywalker because Lucasfilm didn’t use much of his contributions to the story of the film. (Much like they didn’t use his ideas for the entire sequel trilogy after he sold Star Wars to Disney?)."_ -- https://www.thathashtagshow.com/2020/03/01/what-did-george-lucas-think-of-the-rise-of-skywalker/

Comment: @Spencer - I've not seen any evidence that they've retconned the meaning of the prophecy (despite their decision to bring the Emperor back from the dead, I mean)

Comment: Star Wars isn’t about destroying the Sith.